# Cakephp 3.x 'URL mismatch in POST data' with SSL

Tags: ssl, cakephp, post, nginx, cakephp-3.0

#### Setup

- CakePHP 3.4.6
- nginx
- SSL redirect for all URLs
- The app lies within a subfolder on the webserver and the nginx-config is appropriately set.

#### Issue

On the live server with SSL (on nginx) I get the following error when using postLink() to delete data (on any form):

```
URL mismatch in POST data (expected '/somewhere/delete/1001' but found
'/somewhere/delete/1001?url=%somewhere%2Fdelete%2F1001')

Cake\Controller\Exception\AuthSecurityException

toggle vendor stack frames
⟩ Cake\Controller\Component\SecurityComponent->_validatePost
CORE/src/Controller/Component/SecurityComponent.php, line 120
⟩ Cake\Controller\Component\SecurityComponent->startup
CORE/src/Event/EventManager.php, line 414
⟩ Cake\Event\EventManager->_callListener
CORE/src/Event/EventManager.php, line 391
⟩ Cake\Event\EventManager->dispatch
CORE/src/Event/EventDispatcherTrait.php, line 78
⟩ Cake\Controller\Controller->dispatchEvent
CORE/src/Controller/Controller.php, line 506
⟩ Cake\Controller\Controller->startupProcess
```

Posting form and saving them works completely fine. The URL seems to be rewritten somewhere during the request.

The HTML contains the action `action="/somewhere/delete/1001"`

So that seems to be fine. Maybe the nginx redirect is modifying this in an not allowed way. Because I have one rule like:

```
rewrite ^/project/abc/webroot/(.*) /project/abc/webroot/index.php?url=$1 last;
```

But I can't remove this rewrite without getting a 404.

However, can I allow this URLs in the beforeFilter for delete action somehow?

Comment: It's gotta be that nginx redirect. What's the purpose of the `?url=$1` part? Taking that off should probably fix the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer od Jose helped me. I had something like:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri$uri$args;
```

as it should be:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri$args;
```

Comment: 3.x note: `index.php` will figure out the `$uri` value itself, and explicitly passing it will only create confusion (e.g. `example.com/foo/bar?/foo/bar`). Using `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;` worked for me

Comment: Present myself would like to thank past myself for the above comment.

Answer (score 0):

In your nginx configuration for your CakePHP you have something like `?url=$uri`. You need to remove that as it serves no purpose and creates this kind of problems.